# Connecting generating functions for binomial and negative binomial distributions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

The generating function for the binomial distribution can be expressed as:

$((1-p)+p)^r=\sum\limits_{k\ge 0} \binom{r}{k}(1-p)^k p^{r-k}$

$=\sum\limits_{k\ge 0} \text{ probability of $k$ failures when stopping at $r$ trials}$

I was tinkering with the negative binomial distribution to understand the "negative" and obtained:

$((1-p^{-1})+p^{-1})^r=\sum\limits_{k\ge 0}\binom{-r}{k}(1-p^{-1})^k(p^{-1})^{-r-k}$

$=\sum\limits_{k\ge 0}\binom{-r}{k}(-1)^k(1-p)^kp^r=\sum\limits_{k\ge 0}\binom{r+k-1}{k}(1-p)^kp^r$

$=\sum\limits_{k\ge 0} \text{ probability of $k$ failures 
when stopping at $r$ successes}$

I'm curious if there is a non-algebraic (ideally combinatorial) motivation for the fact that mapping $p\mapsto p^{-1}$ maps the generating function for number of failures when stopping at $r$ trials to stopping at $r$ successes.

Comment: Those aren't generating functions. They're equations both sides of which are $1$.

Comment: @joriki you can set q=1-p in the first and q'=1-p^{-1} in the second if you'd like

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me in what sense that would lead to a generating function. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: @joriki yeah my comment was wrong, and you're right that I should have made it more explicit. Let x=1-p. The first is then (x+p)^r and the second is (-x/(1-x)+p^{-1})^r. Expand both as series in x. It is a bit uglier this way, unfortunately.